# Opening file and replacing one string to another via bash script

Tags: bash

I have 3 input parameters: filepath, first string and second string.
I need to open the given file and replace the first string with the second one using .sh script.

Comment: [man sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) -- `sed "s/first string/second string/" filepath`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sed` command as follows

```
sed -i 's/search_string/replace_string/' filename
```

Where

- `-i` option is used to modify the content of the original file with the replacement string if the search string exists in the file.
- `s` indicates the substitute command.
- `search_string` contains the string value that will be searched in the file for replacement.
- `replace_string` contains the string value that will be used to replace the content of the file that matches the `search_string` value.
- `filename` contains the filename where the search and replace will be applied.

for more usage info you can read the manual by typing the command

```
man sed
```

---

So your script may look something like this

```
# !/bin/bash

sed -i "s/$2/$3" $1
```